# Unit tests only fail when run by maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, renjin

I'm currently facing the problem that my unit tests are passing when run by eclipse but failing when run by maven.

This is the repository (+ pom.xml):
https://github.com/thorstenwagner/ij-trajectory-classifier

Here is the build log:
https://travis-ci.org/thorstenwagner/ij-trajectory-classifier

This is the output of mvn -v:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (NON-CANONICAL_2015-11-23T13:17:27+03:00_root; 2015-11-   23T11:17:27+01:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.6.3-1-arch", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I've tried to change my java version from 1.7 to 1.6 but this didn't help.

I appreciate any suggestions

Best,
Thorsten

Comment: So does it run generally? Not with Maven?

Comment: just tried it in jidea. doesnt run

Comment: Yes, it does run in eclipse an generally (you can try by start TraJClassifier_Debug.java)

Comment: Have checked in which line those tests are failing which is one of them: `String res = c.classify(sim.generateTrajectory());` ?

Comment: Yes, I've checked this. It's weired because when running the unit test in eclipse this line does not make a problem at all: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/560426/unittest_pass.png

Comment: Do you have [Java assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) enabled in Eclipse? They might be what's failing and Maven has them enabled during tests by default.

Comment: Dear Anton! That it! I've activated them in eclipse and now get the same errors! When I've changed my pom.xml that the assertions are disabled. Now it works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As posted by Anton Koscejev in the comments:
Java assertions are disabled in eclipse by default but enabled in maven by default. I've added `<enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>` to my pom.xml and it works:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
    <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```